# Return function's nest level in postgresql?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

In **MS SQL** you have `@@NESTLEVEL` but what about in **postgresql**?

I check the docs, only found a function that returns the nest level of triggers.
Searched the docs several few times, lot of things there.

So, I'm not sure if I've missed something, thought I'd asked here to be sure.

Anyone knows what function that returns the nest level for functions (if there is any)?

I'd appreciate other workarounds.

Comment: I don't think theres an equivalent. For a workaround, what are you actually trying to do? Are you writing a recursive function in PL/pgSQL? Are you creating dynamic SQL and calling exec on it?

Comment: Something like this: ` RETURN (dbo.fnMoneyToEnglishNL(value, @@NESTLEVEL))` I'm trying to return a value entered into another function the receives the nestlevel.

Comment: I found a copy of that procedure online. If its the same procedure, it doesn't need `@@NESTLEVEL`. It will take a little bit of effort to re-write, but you could just pass an int to track the recursion level to make sure you are not recursing too deep.

Comment: [Obtaining Current Execution Information](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-GET-DIAGNOSTICS-CONTEXT)